# Python print statements happening "in batch" instead of one at a time

Tags: python, linux, macos

Consider the following python code:

```
import time

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in range(10):
        time.sleep(1)
        print(i)
```

Running this code as a shell script (using the Terminal app on MacOS, if that's relevant) does what I expect: after every second, a number is printed to the screen.

However, I also considered the following modified code in which the print statement is changed:

```
import time

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in range(10):
        time.sleep(1)
        print(i, end=' ')
```

Here, the code doesn't print a number per second, but rather it waits 10 seconds and then prints all of the numbers to the screen simultaneously. I'm wondering why this is happening, and if there is a way to fix this so that the numbers print one at a time like in the first example?

Comment: More precisely, it's waiting until the buffer is full or the script ends, whichever comes first. Waiting 10 seconds is a consequence of the script exiting after the loop completes, which takes 10 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work just fine

```
import time

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in range(10):
        print(i, end=' ',flush=True)
        time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding the `flush=True` (see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=print#print)) keyword disables the buffering of the print function.

```
import time

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in range(10):
        time.sleep(1)
        print(i, end=' ', flush=True)
```